# Problems Pinging VM from Another VM

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, virtual-machines, virtualbox, domain-controller

I have 2 virtual machines that can not ping/access one another.

I am setting up a exchange server, and a domain controller as guest machines in virtualbox. All machines including the host are running windows server Datacenter 2008 R2. I have my networking set to "bridged", and static ip's set in both the virtual machines, and host (but not on the network adapters). Both machines can be pinged from the outside, and can ping the outside. The machines are both on the same ip subnet. The host can ping both virtual machines as well.

Summary:

- servers can ping everything but the other VM
- Networking is set in bridged mode in VM
- Servers are running Datacenter 2008 R2
- The Exchange is 2010 Standard

The ip's are as follows:

- exchange server: 172.16.10.14
- Domain Controller: 172.16.10.24
- Host: 172.16.10.4
- DNS: 8.8.8.8
- Default Gateway: 172.16.10.1

The Hosts network adapters are setup as follows:

- Lan adapter 1: DNS - Bridged in VBox to Exchange Server VM
- Lan adapter 2: DNS - Bridged in VBox to Domain controller VM
- Lan adapter 3: 172.16.10.4

Host:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b16e:2a16:9687:6476%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.4
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4d40:2b97:f7b:9f78%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.102
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2d68:6486:4a4c:bde9%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.119
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.1

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::742d:c91e:28c:2510%20
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.220.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::9858:75b6:85bf:51b4%22
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.14.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::26:1223:c499:1417%28
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::dda:24e7:c94b:e12%33
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.146.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Exchange:

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::61c5:cacc:22e2:22b3%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.14
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.1

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:4137:9e76:8be:33f8:53ef:f5f1
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::8be:33f8:53ef:f5f1%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

Domain Controller

```
Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4969:c85a:a3ef:728e%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.24
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.10.1
```

Comment: May we get the output of ipconfig for both servers as well as the host?

Comment: I am working on the virtual servers ipconfig output now...

Comment: Woah. Try reformatting the output of ipconfig, it's too hard to read in it's current form. I don't see the DNS settings for the NIC's. Are you pinging the servers by name or ip address?

Comment: I am pinging Ip addresses

Comment: Why on earth are you using virtualbox when you have hyper-v available?

Comment: What does tracert from one system to the other show you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exchange to ping AD, it will need to go out the host adapter, and then back in the host adapter (or the other host adapter, since you have two on the same subnet, and I'm not sure which one is bound to which).  Try disabling the windows firewall on the host (or heck, all 3) then, if that works, start adding back the rules till you find the one that's causing the issue.

Also, you have a couple of VMWare and a couple of VBOX adapters on your host.. if you have a bunch of other VM's using nat, that's probably fine, but running both VMWare and VBox at the same time is going to cause resource conflicts..